# Approximating convex in image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, convex-hull

I'm trying to implement this paper on [Traffic Light Detection and Recognition]. So far I've  found the blobs in the image (using `regionprops`) and then checked the ones that fulfill the criteria:

1. Dimension Ratio
2. No holes
3. Convex approximation

I'm done with Dimension Ratio and No holes.

The input image I used is: [Original Image](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1524779_10153642995125182_414999862_n.jpg). I've applied the top hat operator `imtophat`, binarized it using Otsu thresholding method `graythresh`, and obtained [this image](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/1005855_10153642994835182_2113794759_n.jpg) with the blobs (blobs that fulfilled the dimension Ratio & No holes criteria are included in image).

**Now I'm stuck with the `Convex Approximation`, I'm trying to find the blobs that are convex enough to be accepted as a candidate for the traffic light. How should I check if the blobs detected are convex enough to be accepted?**

Comment: Why not just checking if they're shape is round?

Comment: see the `eccentricity` property in `regionprops`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that I cannot get good results from the image after your processing (the 2nd image link). I tried to use a slightly different method to extract the red light in your original image. Hopefully it can help you a little bit.
First of all, you may need to convert the RGB to the [Lab space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space). Actually it is very suitable to handle the image in that space, and some operations can maximize the difference between red and green light. Since there is only a red light in your image, I won't go that complicated. I only used b-channel for further processing.

```
file='https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1524779_10153642995125182_414999862_n.jpg';
I=imread(file);Irgb=I;

colorTransform = makecform('srgb2lab');
I = applycform(I, colorTransform);
b = I(:,:,3);
I=double(b);
Imin=min(I(:));
Imax=max(I(:));
I=(I-Imin)/(Imax-Imin);
imshow(I)
```

Will get you:

[image]

Next, we remove the line/square structure, indeed they have very strong intensity that may impact our further result:

```
se = strel('line',20,0);
I = imtophat(I,se);
figure,imshow(I)
```

You will have:

[image]

In the next step we are trying to find out the local maximum value in the image:

```
roi=20;thresh=0.5;
local_extr = ordfilt2(I, roi^2, ones(roi)); 
% Get local maxima and reject candidates below a threshold
result = (I == local_extr) & (I > thresh);
% Get indices of extrema
[r, c] = find(result);
% Show them
figure;imshow(I, []); hold on;
plot(c, r, 'r.');hold off
```

You will see:

[image]

In fact the red light has already been tagged (I saw another red point in your original image, but I assume that is a walking sign with the red hand shape instead of a circle red light, so herein I won't consider that part.)

Finally we use the `regionprops` with the `eccentricity` property, and find out the region with the least eccentricity, that will look more alike a circle shape:

```
for i=1:length(c)

    I1=I(r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi);
    I1=im2bw(I1);

    labeledImage = bwlabel(I1);
    blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage,'eccentricity'); 
    if isempty(blobMeasurements)
        e(i)=Inf;
    else
        e(i)=blobMeasurements.Eccentricity;
    end

end
[a,idx]=min(e);

res = zeros(size(I,1),size(I,2),3); 
i=idx;
res( r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi ,1) = Irgb(r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi,1);
res( r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi ,2) = Irgb(r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi,2);
res( r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi ,3) = Irgb(r(i)-roi:r(i)+roi,c(i)-roi:c(i)+roi,3);
figure,imshow(uint8(res))
```

The result:

[image]